# Problem with CLI

Tags: magento2, php, cli, command-line

Hello i have an error of every command i press in CLI.
Following this Error

> Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This
>   message will be suppressed on further calls in
>   /var/www/vhosts/nuovamoda.gr/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81

http://prntscr.com/kv28nb 
Also i have in plesk php version 7.0 but in CLI shows me 7.2 
http://prntscr.com/kv297k 
Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems your cli and your server versions are different. You should do two things here.

1. Make both cli and your server (Apache/Nginx) php version same.
2. Make sure the version you are going to use is officially supported by Magento.

PHP 7.2.X is not an officially supported version. Please [**see the versions which are officially supported**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). In short, you can use version: **7.0.13 - 7.0.x** or **7.1.x**